# Creating a map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

Im wanting to create a map with a float (or double) key and a char value.
I have:

```
Map<double, char> memory = new HashMap<double, char>();
```

However this is returning errors when compiling.
The errors are saying unexpected error type for all 4 types (left and right).
Another error says: type Map does not take parameters
How do I fix this? Or is there a better approach to making a dictionary?
Thank you, David

*Adapted*
The code is now:

```
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
```

It is in the class named GameLogic.
But this returns this error message upon compiling:

```
GameLogic.java:5: type Map does not take parameters
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
```

Extended code:

```
public class GameLogic
{
    Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
    public static int position;
    public static char currentBlock;
    public static int currentGold;
    public static int startingPosition;



public GameLogic()
{
    currentGold=0;
}


public void player_position()
{
...
```

Comment: Read a tutorial on generics.

Comment: Additionally, using a floating-point value as a key is nearly always a bad idea, since floating-point equality is tricky.

Comment: Use Wrapper types. `Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 3):

Like this, in Java 5 and up:

```
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
```

Or like this, in Java 7 and up:

```
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<>();
```

In Java you can't create a generic collection of primitive types, so you must use the wrapper classes - so `double` becomes `Double`, and `char` becomes `Character`.

Answer (score 2):

Right way to declare the map is :

```
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
```

Is there any specific reason why you are using Double values as key ?

Comment: In Java6 and up, writing an empty diamond (`<>`) at the constructor call is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, thats got rid of the 4 errors but is still leaving an error.
    GameLogic.java:5: type Map does not take parameters
        Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();

Comment: @user3344370 you should edit in your code to further describe the problem

Comment: @Kakarot Im wanting the key to be similar to that of coordinates with the value being the character at that position. E.G key is 1.5 value is #  or key is -14.31 and value is G.

Comment: Why not store the co-ordinate as String value ?

Comment: @Kakarot Because I am wanting to do arithmetic with those numbers before setting them as a key.

Comment: public static Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();    this syntax works for me. Have you added import java.util.Map; in your code

Comment: I have import java.util.*;
Am also using scanner and array list so its imported OK.

Comment: @pokeairguy can you paste a few lines of the code where you are getting the error

Comment: @Kakarot I've added the above and after lines in the original question. I tried a screenshot but I dont have enough reputation to insert pictures yet.