# Creating a map in Java, parameter error

Tags: java, dictionary

I currently have this piece of code:

```
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
```

However it returns this error upon compiling:

```
GameLogic.java:5: type Map does not take parameters
Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();
   ^
1 error
```

I have no idea why its doing this as I see no reason it should after looking at other questions. It is within the 'GameLogic' class. Please could someone help.

Comment: Which `Map` type are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a map in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976691/creating-a-map-in-java)

Comment: HashMap?? I'm new to Java so unsure of the names and how it works.

Comment: What are the exact import statements?

Comment: try HashMap<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>(); and let me know if you get any error

Comment: @Zavior import java.util.*;

Comment: @Kakarot That seems to have worked! Thank you very much. If I get any more problems later I will be sure to ask. Again, thank you for your help, much appreciated :)

Comment: @pokeairguy: do you have a self defined class `Map`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I do have a class Map which is linked to in the GameLogic class. However I created a new completely seperate class with only the creation of this map and that kicked up the same error.

Comment: @pokeairguy: it is probably causing ambiguity and preferring your self defined class over the actual one. Try it like this: `java.util.Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Then that custom Map class is the culprit. To specify using java.util.Map you need to explicitly mention it : java.util.Map<Double, Character> memory = new HashMap<Double, Character>();

Answer (score 2):

Two possible mistakes:

- You are using JKD 1.4
- You imported something else than `java.util.Map`

Answer (score 0):

You may have imported the wrong `Map` class. `java.util.Map` takes parameters.