# Type HashMap does not take parameters

Tags: java, shadowing

I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-klDVEtwkM) about HashMap in java. it has [below code](http://www.itcuties.com/java/hashmap-example/).

```
// Create the HashMap
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Put data
hm.put("Katie", "Android, WordPress");
hm.put("Magda", "Facebook");
hm.put("Vanessa", "Tools");
hm.put("Ania", "Java");
hm.put("Ania", "JEE");    // !! Put another data under the same key, old value is overridden

// HashMap iteration
for (String key: hm.keySet())
    System.out.println(key+":"+hm.get(key));
```

so I wrote my below code, using it to practice HashMap (almost same code)

```
package hashmap;
import java.util.*;

public class HashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

        hm.put("Katie", "Android, WordPress");
        hm.put("Magda", "Facebook");
        hm.put("Vanessa", "Tools");
        hm.put("Ania", "Java");
        hm.put("Ania", "JEE");   

    }
}
```

But the class didn't compile give error "***Type HashMap does not take parameters***" So I searched for answers where I [got this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977204/creating-a-map-in-java-parameter-error)

one of answers says

> Two possible mistakes:
>
> You are using JDK 1.4
>
> You imported something else than java.util.Map

So I imported `java.util.Map` but netbeans gives that error and say the import has not used. Then I `java.util.*;` but result was same. I don't know if this is novice mistake of my IDE fault.

My jdk 1.8 and Netbeans 8.0.2 in windows 8.1

Comment: Nvm. You are obscuring HashMap with the naming of your class. Totally overlooked this. Credit to @manouti

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're naming your class `HashMap` which is shadowing the `java.util.HashMap`. Just rename it to something else.

Comment: Or use `java.util.HashMap` when creating the map : `new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();` but this is NOT recommended

Comment: @Gaël Indeed but it's much better to rename.

Comment: Got it Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `public class HashMap` custom class hides `java.util.HashMap`, and your custom `HashMap` is not generic, so `new HashMap<String, String>()` is not valid for you custom class.

Comment: Got it Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that not to use same class name as a **HashMap** because it is a Implements of Map Technique in Java and also use Map.entry interface as a objects in for each loop . I hope the below code will help someone with a new beas of HashMap.

```
import java.util.*;
public class QueQue {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hm.put("Peter", 10);
    hm.put("Nancy", 8);
    hm.put("Lily", 9);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> x : hm.entrySet())//entrySet()=Returns a set of all the entries in the map as Map.Entry objects.
    {
        System.out.println(" The String Value in Hashmap is " + x.getKey());
      System.out.println(" The Integer Value in Hashmap is " +x.getValue());
    }
 }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use existingJavaType, for those who want to use Map properties

```
{
    "existingJavaType": "java.util.Map<String, String>",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type" : "string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have name my file as HashMap, i updated it to some other name it resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).