# Importing packages in Java OSx

Tags: java, macos

I have been learning Java on OSx (v10.11.3). Recently when I tried to import utility package I got the following error in compilation:

```
Map.java:6: error: type Map does not take parameters
        Map <String,String> map= new HashMap <String,String>();
            ^
1 error
```

What should I do?
I'm using xCode and compiling it using Terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a map in Java, parameter error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977204/creating-a-map-in-java-parameter-error)

Comment: What is your JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring *your own* class named `Map`. Avoid naming your own types the same as any of the standard types provided by the JDK.